# 'pg' works locally, but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, rails-postgresql, pg

`pg 0.18.4` works just fine in my development environment but not in Heroku. Locally, it first failed when I just ran `bundler install` but then succeeded when I manually ran `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`. I tried provisioning a Heroku Postgres add-on, to no avail.

When I run `git push heroku master`, I get the following output:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        current directory: /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
remote:        /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160123-315-8ytli9.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
remote:        Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
remote:        sh: 1: /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config: not found
remote:        sh: 1: /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config: not found
remote:        checking for libpq-fe.h... no
remote:        Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-pg
remote:        --without-pg
remote:        --enable-windows-cross
remote:        --disable-windows-cross
remote:        --with-pg-config
remote:        --with-pg-dir
remote:        --without-pg-dir
remote:        --with-pg-include
remote:        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
remote:        --with-pg-lib
remote:        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
remote:        /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
...
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory: /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
remote:        /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160123-315-8ytli9.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
remote:        Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
remote:        sh: 1: /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config: not found
remote:        sh: 1: /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config: not found
remote:        checking for libpq-fe.h... no
remote:        Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-pg
remote:        --without-pg
remote:        --enable-windows-cross
remote:        --disable-windows-cross
remote:        --with-pg-config
remote:        --with-pg-dir
remote:        --without-pg-dir
remote:        --with-pg-include
remote:        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
remote:        --with-pg-lib
remote:        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_a5396c397d6502ad1b8bd59388bde2be/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

My Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.3.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Server
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'figaro'

# Database
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'default_value_for'

# Json
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'oj'
gem 'json-schema'
gem 'responders'

# OAuth
gem 'doorkeeper'

group :production do
  # Heroku
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  # Exceptions
  gem 'exception_notification'
end

group :development do
  # Deployment
  gem 'capistrano', '3.3.3'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-postgresql'
  gem 'capistrano-safe-deploy-to', '~> 1.1.1'

  # Server
  gem 'spring'

  # Database
  gem 'rails-erd'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Error Pages
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'

  # Database
  gem 'faker'

  # Debug
  gem 'byebug'

  # Logging
  gem 'lograge'

  # Testing
  # This can't just be in group :test because of https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/148
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  # Database
  # Mocking
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  # Cleaning
  gem 'database_cleaner'

  # Code Coverage
  gem 'simplecov', require: false

  # Debug
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'

  # Profiling
  # https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/rspec-prof/issues/10
  gem 'rspec-prof', git: 'https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/rspec-prof.git'
end

group :doc do
  # RDoc
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
end
```

**Update**: Heroku Help is at wit's end.

When I create a new Rails app and deploy it (same `pg` version, there are no problems. What files in my misbehaving app could possibly cause such different behavior? I'm working on isolating the problem, but no such luck so far.

Comment: Have you [provisioned the postgres addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql)? You can check that with `heroku addons | grep POSTGRES`.

Comment: I just did (the command you gave shows postgres), and I still have the same error.

Comment: Strange, might be the wrong buildpack on Heroku. Try to issue `heroku buildpacks`; is the result "heroku/ruby"?

Comment: It has no buildpack set. I used `heroku create` like it says in the documentation and haven't done anything else except for adding the PostgreSQL addon. The stack is `cedar-14`.

Comment: Try `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby`. It shouldn't be necessary but it won't harm. Then try to push your repo again.

Comment: Same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you add your Gemfile to the question?

Comment: There we go. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Sorry I don't see anything wrong there either… The last thing I'd personally try would be to destroy and recreate the Heroku app. I use Heroku for most of my projects and I have never seen this problem.

Comment: I already destroyed it (twice) and recreated it (twice). Either way, thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: do you try it in `production` environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [Bundler configuration](http://bundler.io/v1.2/bundle_config.html). To make sure you don't have anything there, run `bundle config` and possibly `bundle remove <config name>`. In this case, try `bundle remove build.pg` in case you set something that's conflicting with the defaults.